# How to Define Schema for Nested attributes with existing pyspark dataframe with string type and then print with json

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a data frame with column model_code as string type and I have convert column to model.code and when I print `df.toJSON()` then it is `{"model.code":"xyz"}` but I have requirement to print the json like- `{"model":{"code":"xyz"}}`. How can achieve this using either pyspark or pandas?

Sample dataframe:

| model.code | model.name |
| --- | --- |
| 700 | Desktop |
| 250 | Tablet |

expected output:

```
[{"model":{"code":"700","name":"Desktop"}},{"model":{"code":"250","name":"Tablet"}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using [`toJSON()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toJSON.html) and then use a `map` on the output RDD to manipulate the JSON string.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[(700, 'Desktop'), (250, 'Tablet')], schema = ['model.code', 'model.name'])
>>> df.show()
+----------+----------+
|model.code|model.name|
+----------+----------+
|       700|   Desktop|
|       250|    Tablet|
+----------+----------+

>>> import json
>>> df.toJSON() \
...   .map(lambda x: json.loads('{"model":'+x.replace('model.','')+'}')) \
...   .collect()
[{'model': {'code': 700, 'name': 'Desktop'}}, {'model': {'code': 250, 'name': 'Tablet'}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct the nested `struct` and then use the `to_json` function to convert to a json string.

```
df = df.select(F.collect_list(F.to_json(
    F.struct(F.struct(F.col('`model.code`').alias('code'), F.col('`model.name`').alias('name')).alias('model'))))
)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: above solution is working fine, but i have many field that is identified run time on dataframe. and when i declare all field in above struct. and that field is not found in dataframe then it throw error., but some of data frame have those column so it work.
how to check the condition like above if model.code column is exists in data frame or not because if not found then it throw error.